# Use video script as div background [ HTML / CSS ]

Tags: css, html, video, background

Sorry if my tune is not good.
I have this code of html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="video_bg"> ---- Some Code to execute ---</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.video_bg{
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  float:left;
  }
```

and have a video embed code this

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/71906867" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Question:**
Can i use this video as background of div "video_bg" by using any script or css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use the jquery.videobackground plugin.

Read here: http://georgepaterson.github.io/jquery-videobackground/

Comment: This gets pretty messed up if the user resizes the browser at all.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want to place some texts images etc. on the background's video ? 
If you mean something like this , you can do it by positioning your div's . 
Something like this :

```
<div class="video_bg"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/71906867" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe><p class="text">Some text goes here</p></div>
.video_bg iframe{
width: 500px;
height:281px;
position: relative;
}
.text {
position:absolute;
font-size: 20px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I mean place video as background image. Use a video as a background instead of a image